# Not able to set Opportunity Owner based on Account

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

I am going to set Opportunity Owner based on it's account Owner but not sure what's going wrong..

Can somebody point me what i am doing wrong in this code ?

Code :

```
    trigger SetAmountfromOTTtoSFDC on Opportunity (Before Insert, Before Update) {

    if(Trigger.IsInsert || Trigger.IsUpdate){

       Map <Id, Id> AccountOwnerIdMap = new Map<Id, Id>();

      for(Account ac : [select id, AccountID__c, OwnerId from Account Limit 10000]){
          AccountOwnerIdMap.put(ac.Id, ac.OwnerId);
      }

      for(Opportunity op : Trigger.New){

        if(op.AccountId != Null){
            op.OwnerId = AccountOwnerIdMap.get(op.AccountId);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used another way to set Owner of Opportunity based on it's Account Owner :

```
trigger SetOppOwnerAsAccountOwner on Opportunity (before insert){
    Set<Id> accIds=new Set<Id>();

    for (Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
         accIds.add(opp.AccountId);
    }

    List<Account> accs=[select id, OwnerId from Account where id in :accIds];
    Map<Id, Account> accById=new Map<Id, Account>();
    accById.putall(accs);

    for (Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
         if (null!=opp.AccountId){
             opp.OwnerId=accById.get(opp.AccountId).OwnerId;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

In the first `for` loop, you're doing this:

```
AccountTextIdMap.put(ac.Owner.Name, ac.Ownerid);
```

Putting the Owner's name (e.g. John Doe) against their Id.

However, whilst looping through Opportunities, you're setting the `OwnerId` by getting the value of the `AccountId` which won't exist in the `Map`.

```
op.OwnerId = AccountTextIdMap.get(op.AccountId);
```

One other thing is that you were trying to assign `OwnerId` without retrieving it in the query, so I'm surprised this didn't throw an error.

**Solution**

What you need to do is, whilst looping through `Account` records is instead of doing:

```
AccountTextIdMap.put(ac.Owner.Name, ac.Ownerid);
```

You should put in the `Account` Id,

So:

```
for (Account ac : [select Id, OwnerId from Account Limit 10000]){
    AccountTextIdMap.put(ac.Id, ac.Ownerid);
}
```

Given you're mapping an Id to another Id, you also may as well change your map to:

```
Map <Id, Id> AccountTextIdMap = new Map<Id, Id>();
```

Then, when you're looping through the following:

```
for(Opportunity op : Trigger.New){

    if(op.AccountId != Null){
        op.OwnerId = AccountTextIdMap.get(op.AccountId);
    }
}
```

Which is looping through Opportunities and checking if it has an associated Account, you will get the `OwnerId` of said associated `AccountId`.

Comment: thanks Dan !! but it still give me the same error "data changed by trigger for field Owner ID: owner cannot be blank"

Comment: @Nihar Can you edit your question to show your updated code?

Comment: updated .. can you please check

Comment: @Nihar That looks fine to me, but obviously it isn't. It maybe worth debugging your `Map` after the first `for` loop to make sure the `AccountId` key you're after is in there, and that it has an `OwnerId` as it's value.

Comment: Ok. let me do debugging !! :)